# Socket.Accept() method is blocking when receiving FTP active mode data connection

Tags: c#, sockets, ftp

Not sure if the partial code below will help but we are having an issue which only happens in a few of our client machines trying to FTP data to the FTP server.

We are taking network traces and trying to find anything unique about these machines.

Here is where our code stops: => `listening_sock.Accept();`

```
//region Try to bind to an available data port
System.Net.IPEndPoint localEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(sIPAddr), (dataPortStart == 0 ? 0 : GetFreePort(dataPortStart, dataPortEnd)));
listening_sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listening_sock.Bind(localEP);
Log.WriteLine("Listening sock bound to IP Address:" + localEP.Address.ToString() + " on port " + localEP.Port.ToString());

//port 20
if (data_sock != null)      // already connected (always so if passive mode)
return;

data_sock = listening_sock.Accept();    // Accept is blocking
listening_sock.Close();
listening_sock = null;
```

Here we can see the send port command was successful (Active FTP) but server responds with a 425:

[image]

My best bet is Firewall. I am checking that too.

Thank you

Comment: Did you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Socket` is created blocking by default. So the [`Socket.Accept`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.socket.accept) should indeed block until a connection request is received.

I assume the problem is not in the code, but the request actually does not come, either because:

- it is blocked by a firewall
- or you have NAT configured incorrectly
- or you have provided a wrong IP address or port number to the server.

Comment: yep the firewall was ON at the windows client. This sucks because I don't get anything back in my TRY CATCH block and the client just hangs there waiting and waiting.... thanks

Comment: That's a correct behavior. The `Socket` class does not know that you expect the connection any time soon. A typical TCP server sits waiting endlessly for incoming connections. An active FTP connection that expects the incoming connection almost immediately in a very specific case.

Comment: this is insane, it should give me an exception after the FTP server closes the connection. This is hanging our windows service :-(

Comment: Do you mean the FTP control connection? How can a low-level class like `Socket` possibly know that you have another connection opened (in an opposite direction) that you consider somehow related to the listening socket? Once you have chosen to implement FTP protocol yourself (why?!?), you have to take care of all these low level peculiarities yourself. If you want .NET framework handle all this for you, use an existing FTP client ([`FtpWebRequest`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest.aspx)), and do not try to build your own!

Comment: That was a project we inherit using a C# ftp class which was re-written from a Java source code somewhere in the open source community. We have to use that because we need to use Active FTP and we need to control the range of ports the FTP server can use to connect back to the client. This was years ago but now I know we can control that in the IIS FTP server (the port range) but we aren't changing anything in this project right now.